# Ubuntu 12.04 impacting wireless speed of other devices

Tags: 12.04, wireless, wireless-access-point

I am having hp-pavilion g7-1310 us laptop and am using ubuntu 12.04 in it. I also have wireless router at my home using which I connect my laptop for internet. I also use that router to connect to other devices.

From last few days, I am facing a weird problem.If I connect my laptop with wireless router, my other devices get speed from 30 MBPS to almost 2 MBPS. I tested this weird problem by connecting using wired connection and if I connect laptop using wired connection , my other devices get proper speed (almost 30 MBPS).

I have no idea why this is happening. Please help me out.

Thanks.
J.M.

Answer (score 0):

I'm new to Ubuntu, and I`ve had the same problem with my Toshiba L675. 
Everything worked great (two cell phones, HP latpop and even Toshiba L675) when Toshiba was running on battery. When I plug-in my Toshiba laptop, connection on other devices goes down from 12Mb/s to 1, maybe 2.
The only difference is that, when Toshiba L675 was running on battery, when I type

```
sudo iwconfig
```

I see among other things `Power Management:on`. On the other hand, when it's plugged-in it turns off the power management and everything works fine.
Turning power management on manually `sudo iwconfig eth1 power on` did the trick for me at first, but I did some more digging, and I found that I had Additional driver installed for my wireless card.
When I`ve deactivated it everything went to normal.
I hope this helps, 'cause it was very frustrating for me.